# How to append string that get's updated to mode line?

Tags: mode-line

I would like to append some information (that changes over time) to the mode line **format** and then use it in the title.

My thought being is that once a minute I would set the frame-title-format to be that of the mode-line-format + pomodoro count.

Something along the lines of:

```
(defun runOnceAMinute ()
   (setq frame-title-format (concat mode-line-format my/PomodoroCount))
)
```

But I can't quite figure out how.

**EDIT**
I would need to update the string that I append. E.g the pomodoro-count would increment after each pomodoro.

**EDIT 2**
I got it to work by editing `mode-line-format` variable and using the eval construct:

```
("%e" ......... "[Pomodorors: " (:eval (number-to-string my/pomCount)) "]")
```

This is not Drew's original answer, but Drew mentioned it in his comment.

Comment: `mode-line-format` has been simplified in recent years to (more or less) just a smallish list of other variables; so you would typically modify one of those child variables (or some further descendant), rather than `mode-line-format` itself. See `C-h v mode-line-format`, and then similarly `C-h v` for any of the component variables you want to learn about.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I want. I edited the mode line:
`(..... "HI" )` and this shows up.
But if I want to print an integer, it doesn't show up?
`(.... (number-to-string my/count))`    any ideas why?

Comment: Read `C-h v mode-line-format` carefully: it describes the behaviour of the various different constructs that you can use, and it's a bit complicated. For more details, see the manual: `C-h i g (elisp) Mode Line Format`

Comment: I read the docu, but can't seem to make sense of how to append an integer to the list?

Comment: I use doom-modeline,add pomodoro segment like this: ```(defun my-eval-string (string)
    "Evaluate elisp code stored in a string."
    (eval (car (read-from-string string))))

  ;; pomodoro
  (doom-modeline-def-segment pomodoro
    "pomodoro segment"
    (my-eval-string "pomodoro-mode-line-string"))```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append it to `global-mode-string`.  If your mode-line format string to append is `my-string` then:

```el
(setq global-mode-string
      (cond ((consp global-mode-string)
             (add-to-list 'global-mode-string my-string 'APPEND))
            ((not global-mode-string)
             (list my-string))
            ((stringp global-mode-string)
             (list global-mode-string my-string))))
```

[If you instead wanted to *pre*pend it to `global-mode-string` then you would remove the `'APPEND` optional argument and reverse the order of the last list: `(list my-string global-mode-string)`.]

Comment: FWIW, nowadays there's also `mode-line-misc-info` (which has `global-mode-string` as a member by default).

Comment: @phils: Yes, there is. Doesn't change my answer, but there's room for plenty of other answers. ;-) There are multiple ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Hello, this is very close to what I want :-). I think I didn't ask the question correctly. Once I've added the pomodoro count, how do I update that number? Each time I call that function, it adds more stuff to the mode line.

Comment: Then instead of adding a constant string to `global-mode-string`, use `(:eval...`. That is really a different question.

Comment: @Drew, I tried `(..... (:eval (number-to-string my/pc)))`   with my/pc being an integer that I set before hand. But the number does not show in mode line?

Comment: @Drew, actually, I got the eval business working. This solves my problem. If you post it up as an answer, I'll go along with that.

Comment: I just realized that you were the one who already answered.

Answer (score 3):

```
(setq-default mode-line-misc-info "My Text Goes Here")
```

Should append the data above to your mode line.