# How to display a python string in the modeline?

Tags: mode-line

I'm using a python script to get my monthly bandwith usage shown as string on the terminal stdout. How can I display & update it periodically in the modeline?

Comment: Check the doc for the variables `mode-line-format` and perhaps `global-mode-string` and `mode-line-misc-info`.

Comment: It's likely this question is a duplicate. Could someone please check for that? Seems like questions about how to put something into the mode-line have been asked many times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append string that get's updated to mode line?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13855/how-to-append-string-that-gets-updated-to-mode-line)

Answer (score 2):

You want to append data to `global-mode-string` [1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13860/9851).

```elisp
(add-to-list 'global-mode-string '(:eval (myfunc)))
```

The function:

```elisp
(defun myfunc ()
   (setq mystring (shell-command-to-string "myshellcommand")))
```

where `myshellcommand` is your python script invocation returning your data string.

Now this might stress the system, so instead

```elisp
 (run-at-time 0 60 'myfunc)
 (defun myfunc2() mystring)
 (add-to-list 'global-mode-string '(:eval myfunc2))
```

So here `myfunc` is called every minute to update `mystring`. `myfunc2` returns `mystring`. We called `myfunc2` rather than `myfunc` in the mode string update thus not calling your script too often.

Edit:

You might want the call to myfunc2 to do some other work but if not, you can add the symbol directly:-

```elisp
(add-to-list 'global-mode-string 'mystring)
```

Comment: Instead of `(defun myfunc2() mystring)` and `'(:eval myfunc2))` you can just use the mode line construct `'mystring` directly.

Comment: thanks, I added that.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to add stuff to the mode line.
One way is to define a global minor-mode and a global string variable, register the variable in `mode-line-format` when the minor mode is active.
Run your Python code with a timer and write the result to the string variable and call `force-mode-line-update` for all windows afterwards.

The following Elisp code demonstrates that. The Python code is replaced by a `(format-time-string " Seconds: %S")` from Elisp. Put in whatever you like there.

- Don't use the `(:eval ...)` construct of `mode-line-format` to run your heavy Python task. That eval may be run much more often than you want!
- Instead of a simple string you can also use a `(:propertize ...)` construct to add fancy text properties. Since you can change these properties by `my-mode-line-update-handler` you can vary the text color from green to red depending on the network load.

```el
;; mode-line-format
(defvar my-mode-line-update-interval 1
  "Mode line update in seconds.")

(defvar my-mode-line-entry ""
  "String holding my actual modeline add-on.
See `mode-line-format'.")
;; We need the following if we want to propertize the string:
(put 'my-mode-line-entry 'risky-local-variable t)

(defun my-mode-line-update-handler ()
  "Mode line update running for `my-mode-line-mode'."
  (setq my-mode-line-entry (format-time-string " Seconds: %S")) ;; here you run your Python code.
  (force-mode-line-update t))

(defvar my-mode-line-timer nil
  "Timer running my function and updating the modeline.")

(define-minor-mode my-mode-line-mode
  "Demonstration of an updating modeline entry."
  :global t
  (when (timerp my-mode-line-timer)
    (cancel-timer my-mode-line-timer))
  (if my-mode-line-mode
      (progn
    (unless (memq 'my-mode-line-entry mode-line-format)
      (setq mode-line-format (nconc mode-line-format (list 'my-mode-line-entry))))
    (setq my-mode-line-timer (run-with-timer 0 my-mode-line-update-interval #'my-mode-line-update-handler)))
    (setq mode-line-format (delq 'my-mode-line-entry mode-line-format))))
```